# Has any philosopher stated that time and space begin in the present moment, and then become the fixed state we observe in the past?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-physics, time, being-and-time

We have a cultural bias based on the arrow of time that strongly implies a lack of free will, and a high probability of a pre-existing future.

I'm interested in finding prior thinking based on the idea that time begins in the present and is understood only as it exists in the past.

Comment: "a pre-existing future, especially on a quantum level" "a quantum, orderly, perfectly predictable process" I don't think you understand what quantum mechanics says about nature, or what a probability amplitude is for that matter. The entire point of the measurement problem is that quantum mechanics is not "a perfectly predictable process". If you have some sort of perfectly predictable version of QM, your Nobel prize is ready and waiting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask.  Sorry, but we are not a discussion site for new theories, promoting personal positions and soliciting discussions is off-topic here. Questions are supposed to be answerable and the answers based on existing literature on philosophy. Perhaps you could look through [SEP entry on time](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time) and rephrase your question by stating more precisely what you are looking for in existing philosophical positions.

Comment: At one extreme -- Dennet, in the 'multiple drafts model' of mental processing sketched in 'Consciousness, Explained' all qualia are only memories, and space and time are qualia.

Comment: To say that this is a discussion site, and in the same sentence, insist that soliciting discussions is "off-topic" is a difficult answer for me to understand.

Comment: I have edited my question to eliminate my own theories. I would still welcome any actual answers, most importantly, answers leading me to philosophers who have worked with the idea that time begins in the present and then becomes fixed in the past, where we observe and measure it as an arrow.

Comment: @TonyPatti Conifold didn't say that this is a discussion site, as it is [explicitly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums) not a discussion site. The sentence reads "Sorry, but we are not a discussion site for new theories, promoting personal positions and soliciting discussions is off-topic here." I don't think anywhere in that sentence is something that means "we are a discussion site". Anyway, I think if you could provide some sort of context for the first sentence of your question, that would help make the question a better fit.

Comment: I.e. what do you mean by a "cultural" bias, who is included in "we", what is a "high probability of a preexisting future" (where does the high probability come from? if the future is preexisting then it exists in the present too, what does that mean? why is our culture biased towards believing that?). What research have you done that shows these things to be true, do you have any quotes that can illuminate their meaning or reinforce these conjectures?

Comment: Saying that this is not a discussion site for specific topics implies that this is a discussion site for other things. What proof do you have of these claims you are making? Is there a list of off-topic subjects I didn't see? Please link.

Comment: Not Here is trolling me, because he has no answers to my simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any philosophers who argue that time has a beginning but a slight adjustment to your idea would lead you to Kant and the Perennial philosophy for which time is not metaphysically-real.

This is a different idea but has many of the same consequences. What you seem to be suggesting is that the time is only ever 'Now' and the past and future are only ever theoretical, and this allows your speculation to work. I think you're probably right about this but pretty much on your own among philosophers. To me the Upanishadic or Buddhist explanation of time seems a lot more plausible and it has widespread support and an extensive literature.

It may also be relevant that the consistent-histories interpretation of QM allows for history to be re-written in every moment, but I'm not enough of a physicist to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very similar to Bertrand Russell's "Five-Minute Hypothesis", or the [Omphalos_hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos_hypothesis)  i.e. that there is no way of proving that the universe did not spring into existence 5 minutes ago, with all of history created at the same time.

This hypothesis basically states that your proposal could be true, and that there is in fact no way of disproving it; because a universe that was created 'now' would be indistinguishable from one that 'got here the long way around'